# Swiftmailer not flush emails on Symfony Controller

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

i have created a simple project for sending emails from swiftmailer, however, messages are delivered from console but not from Controller. My code is

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance('hello','test message', 'text/plain','Cp1252')
    ->setFrom('service@mycompany.com')->setTo('myuser@mycompany.com');
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

- php is 5.6
- smtp server is iis 6
- Apache is installed from xampp
- S.O. is windows server 2008

i tried with symfony 2.7 and symfony 3.0 with swiftmailer 5.4, and with encoding utf-8 and Cp1252

the error message on dev.log is 
    app.ERROR: Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Expected response code 250 but got code "501", with message "501 5.5.4 Invalid Address " [] []

when i send emails from console this works without problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is the problem, Siwftmailer create IDs as aaaabbbbccccddd@hostname, when the IIS server resend the email looking for a hostname, because i test with localhost, the remote smtp server do not recognize source host and trhows error, to solve this issue i run with the hostname in network. However, i do not know, how to avoid this error on development environment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve i run the script with no http://localhost but the network http://hostname, however, i do not know how to run correctly en dev environment